# iOS : Do not cut socket when entring in suspended background

Tags: ios, cordova, nsurlrequest

I use Cordova / Phonegap in my iOS app to load an url. This webpage exchanges some datas with a server with a socket which is open in Javascript in the webpage.

When my iOS application enter in suspended background on iOS, the socket is cut by iOS system. (The socket is opened from Javscript part, not in native iOS)

How can i avoid this behaviour ?

Is the method "setNetworkServiceType" can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The official way is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)! (search for 'Developing a VoIP App' within the document)

In short you have to:

```
- set UIBackgroundModes to voip in the Info.plist file
- before entering background, you need to call the setKeepAliveTimeout:handler
```

Nevertheless I'm not sure if this procedure is realizable using Cordova / Phonegap. Furthermore your app will be rejected if it's not a voip app at all.

Comment: Thanks, yes i have a doubt about the possibility to use NSURLRequest to tag my Cordova webpage as VoIP interface